# If Android service crashes will it bring down App on which it is running?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm writing a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for an Android application component and I want my App to not crash because of any fault in service. By default Is the app is protected from any faulty behavior of background service.

Comment: yes your app crashes if your app service crash. but if you handled exception then you app will be save from crash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question, **Yes**. Your application will be terminated if a service within your application crashes.
 To provide a solution, don't let the service crash. I believe you can prevent a service from crashing if you can prevent whole rest of application. Use `try-catch` or other programming approaches to handle exceptions. Let us know if anything specific in code needs help for those purposes.

**Update:** I was assuming you are using "single process model". 
As the comment suggests, there is more to it. Your **process** will be terminated if a service within that process crashes. Your application will be terminated if the main thread is running under same process.
By default, Android uses same process throughout your application. In that case, the application will be terminated if any exception occurs (because the process is crashed). You can specify different processes to be run for different activities under manifest (if you "really" need it).
See [Process and thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more details on how to do it.

Comment: I don't think it is that easy. There is no simple "yes" answer. It depends. For example, if the `Service` is running in another process, a crashing `Service` will not crash the process where the UI is running. Also, if the `Service` is using worker threads, and a worker thread crashes, this will also not terminate the process. Only if the main thread crashes will the process be terminated.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. I have edited my answer. I was under the assumption that  only one process is being used throughout the application, which is the default scenario. And I think you are wrong on second point. Even if the background thread crashes, the app will crash if the activity (or service) is running in main process.

Comment: Yes, you are right about background thread crashes also crashing the application. Sorry about that. We have a framework in use that catches uncaught exceptions and only exits our app if the main thread crashes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to run your `Service` in a separate process from the rest of your app. If your `Service` crashes, this will not directly crash your app (ie: your activities). However, you then need to figure out how your app should continue to operate once the `Service` has crashed. Of course, your app can attempt to restart the `Service` and/or take other measures.

To do this, just add this to the `<service>` declaration in your manifest:

```
android:process=":remote"
```